# How to set a border or highlight input element when validation fails with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, client-side-validation

I have a table generated from `GridView` defined like that:

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" id="MainContent_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustID&#39;)">Customer ID</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustFirstName&#39;)">First Name</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustLastName&#39;)">Last Name</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1&#39;,&#39;Sort$CustCity&#39;)">City</a></th><th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_0">12</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_0">Anders</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_0">Rohansen</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_0">Takoma Park</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$txtEmail" type="text" value="a.rohansen@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_0" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_0" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_0" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_0" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr><tr style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_1">8</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_1">Deborah</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_1">Damien</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_1">Fresno</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$txtEmail" type="text" value="d.damien@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_1" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_1" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_1" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl03$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_1" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCustID_2">7</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblFirstName_2">Derek</span>
        </td><td>
          <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblLastName_2">Chaddick</span>
        </td><td>
         <span id="MainContent_GridView1_lblCity_2">Fairfield</span>
       </td><td>
         <input name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$txtEmail" type="text" value="d.chaddick@testemail.com" id="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_2" />
          <span data-val-controltovalidate="MainContent_GridView1_txtEmail_2" data-val-errormessage="Must enter Email Address" data-val-validationGroup="grpEmail" id="MainContent_GridView1_ctl00_2" data-val="true" data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val-initialvalue="" style="visibility:hidden;">Must enter Email Address</span>
           <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$btnUpdate" value="Update Email" onclick="return ValidateEmail(this);WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl04$btnUpdate&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;grpEmail&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="MainContent_GridView1_btnUpdate_2" ButtonType="Button" />

         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When validating email field, I want to highlight or set border to red for the email text field. When doing that in my `ValidateEmail(btnObj)` function

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input:name').style.borderColor="red";
```

I get an error : "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name".

I was able to access text field by `(btnObj).siblings('input:text').val()`

What is the right way to do that?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change CSS values with jQuery with the following:

```
.css("border", "1px solid red")
```

you could also easily select the required element by its type

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input[type="text"]').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Comment: What can I use to remove border? I'm trying to use something like `$(txtObj).css("border-style", "none"` but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "None" is not a valid border-style. Instead simply try: $(txtObj).css("border", "none");

Answer (score 0):

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input:name').
```

is a **jquery Object** and you are trying to use `Vanilla Javascript method` on it

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input:name').
```

should be

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input[name]')[0].  // Selects inputs with name attribute
```

Also if you intend to target inputs with the name attribute, your selector has to be changed as to

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input[name]')
```

When you are using jQuery why not just use the .css method provided by the library

```
$(btnObj).siblings('input[name]').css({
    borderColor : 'red'
});
```